# How do I get in this locked area inside a BoI: Repentance crawlspace?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-repentance

The latest DLC, Repentance, includes a new design for crawlspaces. This new room layout contains 2 pedestal items, one on top of the rightmost ladder, the other seemingly unaccessible, locked behind a wall.

[image: Walled item]

I've already tried bombing the wall, to no avail. I've used a single bomb, since that's all I had. How do I get to that item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This apparently is a new crawlspace layout added in Repetance - I don't think it can be experienced in previous versions of the game. It is getting a lot of posts on the game reddit recently.

Anyway, I suppose this layout is intended as a troll because ***most of the times*** you won't be able to get the item - apparently no player found a way to create an opening / move the wall yet.

Still, even if an hidden passage isn't an option there are some possible workarounds with very specific items:

- [Mr ME!](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.fandom.com/wiki/Mr._ME!): the ghost isn't affected by walls, so you can use it to pick up the item and bring it to Isaac
- [HOW TO JUMP!](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_Jump): apparently works based on some let's play videos, but I don't know if this is intended since it would mean you are jumping in the third direction in a 2d sideview space. Don't be surprised if this if fixed out... Or maybe it is a subtle reference to flipping in Super Paper Mario???
- [Diplopia](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.fandom.com/wiki/Diplopia) - providing that you are lucky enough that the copy spawns in an accessible location. Yet, if you were lucky enough to get Diplopia and the room in the first place you must be a lucky guy.
- [Void](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.fandom.com/wiki/Void): the fact that you can't get to the item doesn't mean that Void can't absorb it.
- [Stitches](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.fandom.com/wiki/Stitches): didn't had the opportunity to verify this yet, but technically the familiar should still be able to pass through the wall in the crawlspace and as such Isaac should be able to swap place with it.
- [Moving Box](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.fandom.com/wiki/Moving_Box): see void, you can absorb the item and then unpack in a different room.
- [Pluto](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.fandom.com/wiki/Pluto): for some reason Pluto will allow you to pass thru the wall. Just don't expect to see this combo very often....

What does not work:

- Any form of flight. This make sense since the room is meant to be viewed from the side (and that is the reason HOW TO JUMP! seems a bug).
- Bombs and red key - nothing seems to be able to break the wall or place a door.
- Items like Boomerang or Jaw Bone that can only work on pickups items

Comment: Another solution: Moving box, which allows to "swallow" the item and drop it in another room.